# Limit the text overflow in Python pptx text frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm new to the python pptx library (and to stack overflow as well). Kindly assist me with the issue I'm facing with the pptx text frame module.

I've been trying to add a list of text in Powerpoint slide using pptx (you can also suggest any other library if that helps).
However, I'm stuck at a point where the text basically overflows and gets added outside the text frame (textbox) if there is extra text.

To be clearer, I want the extra text to be deleted or maybe not added at all. It should just limit to the height of the text frame and check out.

An example:

[image: PLEASE CHECK THE REFFERRED ISSUE HERE]

The code is quite straightforward and goes like this so far:

```
input_df = pd.read_excel("list.xls")

prs = Presentation("template.pptx")
slide = prs.slide_layouts

new_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[2])
title = new_slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Testing"

shape2 = new_slide.shapes[1].text_frame
shape2.clear()

p = shape2.paragraphs[0]
run = p.add_run()
run.text = '\n\n'.join(str(i) for i in input_df['Texts'])
font = run.font
font.name = 'Arial'
font.size = Pt(11)


prs.save("test.pptx")
```

Please let me know in case I'm missing out on something. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I don't think you can perform the computations necessary to chop the text at the point where it would spill out of the box. That would need advanced metrics calculations and have to take into account varying fonts in the chunk of text. (Or maybe I misunderstood the question.)

Comment: @MartinPacker -  Thanks for your reply.
Well, if not chopping, what I would like is to for the program to stop inputting any more text in the textframe once it is full.
I mean my basic issue is that I have a list of (for eg.) 200 product names and then I want the program to only fill in until what a textframe from the layout can hold for the slide (and not overflow it).
Even to create some kind of logic, I'd need to access either the textbox size or the frame size if at all it could keep adjusting with new entries.

Comment: Text box dimensions are available. You can both read and set them. (In my code I do both.)

If your product names are short enough to each fit on a single line you could use the font size to work out how many lines to put on a page. But you can't calculate where to stop accepting input. That would require VBA in PowerPoint itself (and python-pptx doesn't drive PoiwerPoint itself).

Comment: @MartinPacker - Got your point! So there is no way for python to automate the PowerPoint like VBA does it?

Comment: That's correct: It's manipulating the file without going through PowerPoint. Indeed you don't even have to have PowerPoint installed.